# C++ winapi - new thread on button click causes fatal error

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, fatal-error

Consider the following code:

```
static void crossValidate(HWND hwnd) {
     // Do-stuff (image processing mostly)
     cv::imshow("ROC CURVE", roc);
     cv::waitKey(1);
}

static LRESULT mainOnCommand(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
     int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
     int wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

     switch (wmId) {
          // ...
          case IDMC_CROSSVALID: { crossValidate(hwnd); break; }
          // ...
     }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
     // ...
     case WM_COMMAND: return mainOnCommand(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam); break;
     // ...
}
```

Everything was great until I realized that when `crossValidate()` was called the whole program was frozen, simply because `crossValidate()` execution takes hours to finish and the window can't receive other messages. I guess what I need is to start a new thread for `crossValidate()`. And that's exactly what I did:

```
std::thread crossValidateThread; // global
// ...
// ...

// Inside mainOnCommand()
// ...
case IDMC_CROSSVALID: { crossValidateThread = std::thread(crossValidate,hwnd); break; }
// ...
```

Now the program was not frozen but I have 2 new problems:

1) When `crossValidate()` finish it's execution, the window displaying ROC Curve simply disappear (see 2 last lines of code inside `crossValidate()`)

2) `crossValidate()` works only the first time. What I mean is that the first time I click the button `crossValidate()` executes (still ROC window disappear), but after it's first execution if I press the button one more time the program crashes with a fatal error.

Comment: if you run your program in a debugger, what results do you get?

Comment: @xaxxon Well, I use vs13 and all it does is displaying a window saying fatal error

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, that doesn't mean it will disappear. I mean when I don't use a thread to call `crossValidate()` the window doesn't disappear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
crossValidateThread = std::thread(crossValidate,hwnd);
```

If you assign to a std::thread that has been started, but not joined or detached, your program will end.

The first time, it hasn't been started yet, so that's fine.   The second time, there's already a thread there, so your program crashes.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread

> If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called.

Comment: @DimChtz Either that, or join the old before creating a new thread.

Comment: It depends on whether you need to know when it's done.   join() will block until it's done.   You may need to create a vector of them if you need to store N concurrent threads.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. What about the `cv::window`? Any idea why is it closing?

Comment: maybe one of those things you're doing after your      // Do-stuff (image processing mostly) bit?   it's tough to tell without the full real code.

Comment: *"What about the `cv::window`? Any idea why is it closing?"* - I suppose because it's created on a thread that doesn't run a message loop and doesn't dispatch messages.